# What should be the wording of divorce?

Tags: sharia, prophet-muhammad, talaq

I want to ask that if husband say "talaq talaq takaq" or say is talaq from my side instead of saying "I divorce you" would that be considered as divorce or not?

Answer (score 1):

**It should be elucudated that divorcing consists of some specific conditions which should be observed. For instanceو it could be declared that “Divorce or talaq contract ought to be recited with the correct Arabic words in a way such that 2 just men (as witnesses) listen to it.**

In regard to the sentences (phrase) of talaq, the person (man) who intends to divorce, ought to utter the following sentence:

> **زَوْجَتِي فلان(الاسم الزوجه) طالِق**

Actually the man utters the sentence above (note: He must name her wife instead of the word FOLAN at the mentioned phrase).

---

**Reference**:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8230)
- [www.hoseini.org](http://www.hoseini.org/talaq.pdf)